# What is the difference in .toSet and .toSet()?

Tags: scala

What happens when you write `List(1,2,3).toSet()` instead of `List(1,2,3).toSet`? The first expression returns a `Boolean`. Why?

Comment: It seems to be equivalent to `.toSet`[`.apply()`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Set@apply(elem:A):Boolean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing `List(1,2,3).toSet()` is equivalent to:

```
List(1,2,3).toSet(())

List(1,2,3).toSet.apply(())

List(1,2,3) toSet ()

List(1,2,3).toSet apply ()
```

That is, the `()` in your call isn't an empty `apply`. It is a `Unit`. So `toSet` converts the `List` to a `Set`. The compiler sees the `()`, but knows there is no such thing as an empty `apply` method on `Set`, so it instead assumes you must be trying to call `Set#apply` without the parentheses, and are passing `()` to it as an argument.

This is confusing, which is why this usage is deprecated.

```
$ scala -deprecation

scala> List(1,2,3).toSet()
<console>:11: warning: Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want.
        signature: GenSetLike.apply(elem: A): Boolean
  given arguments: <none>
 after adaptation: GenSetLike((): Unit)
       List(1,2,3).toSet()
                        ^
```

Heed those deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent of .Set .apply() as Bergi mentioned.

But there is more; beacuse that apply() method takes `elem: A` parameter but here we are giving nothing by just using toSet(), and compiler adaptations helps us(but may be shouldn't) and changes it to

```
GenSetLike((): Unit)
```

which satisfy signature, but this is deprecated, check [here.](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5cb3d4ec14488ce2fc5a1cc8ebdd12845859c57d/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Adaptations.scala)

Edit: If you run repl with -deprecated you should see the warning

```
<console>:11: warning: Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want.
    signature: GenSetLike.apply(elem: A): Boolean
    given arguments: <none>
    after adaptation: GenSetLike((): Unit)
    List(1,2,3).toSet.apply()
    res1: Boolean = false
```